# AppEngine appcfg reporting 503 and 500 when "Getting current resource limits"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've have been making changes and uploading them for testing on AppEngine Python 2.7 runtime.

When uploading I only get as far as seeing the message "Getting current resource limits". The next expected message is "Scanning files on local disk", but this never comes, I always get an error instead.

My last successful deploy was at 11:05 AM (UK time).
My next attempt to deploy was at 11:09 AM and this failed with a 503 error

```
ERROR __init__.py:1294 An error occurred processing file  '': HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable. Aborting.
```

Ever since 11:09 i've been getting HTTP 503 errors. I have also had 1, HTTP 500 error.

I normally use the command line and have tried this multiple times and have also tried using the GUI "Google AppEngine Launcher" too. It was when using the GUI that I got the 500 error, using the command line always gives me 503.

```
ERROR __init__.py:1294 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error. Aborting.
```

I have tried getting more information to be reported by using the --verbose and --noisy options but they don't give any further information. The command line I am using is:

```
python appcfg.py --email=*my_email* update "*my_path*" -A *alternate_appID* -V *alternateVersion*
```

This command was working at 11:05 but 4 minutes later it does not. In those 4 minutes I only changed a single line of code (verified using git diff) and have tried rolling that change back so that the code being deployed is the same as the code that I know already deployed fine.

Am I forgetting something obvious or doing something stupid?
Is this happening to anyone else? 
Has this previously happened to anyone else? If so how did you resolve it?

Comment: Sometimes it just hangs up - I've encountered this as well. My solution: just destroy the current attempt, run appcfg rollback and try again.

Comment: Good general tip, and that normally does work for me but in this instance nothing I tried seemed to get around the problem. Everything has been running fine since then though.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. Fortunately, I was able to deploy the project successfully.

Just stop the **appengine** from running your project and try to deploy it again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't believe it.... I tried deploying again just before posting this question. Everything the same and it works now.

12:30 UK time.... so just a bit of an AppEngine issue? Did anyone else run into this?

Can anyone explain what was going on? I can't be affording to spend 90 minutes messing about everytime I want to deploy my app...